# Is it "safe" to update the express-session directly in the database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session

My scenario is as follows:

- I need to add a property to the session inside of a webhook.
- I do not have access to req.session inside this webhoob.
- Therefore, I found a clever solution to pass in the sessionID to the webhook in the payloads metadata. I Can then run the following code:

```
const found_session = await mongoose.connection.db.collection('sessions').findOne({ _id: data.metadata.session_id });
const session_data = JSON.parse(found_session.session);
session_data.customer_id = data.customer;
await mongoose.connection.db.collection('sessions').updateOne({ _id: data.metadata.session_id }, {
  $set: { session: JSON.stringify(session_data) },
);
```

My concern is that when asking openai if this is safe, it explains to me:

"When you modify the session data directly in the database, you may invalidate any existing session tokens that were issued before the modification. This happens because the session token is typically generated based on the session data, so if the session data changes, the token may no longer be valid."

I was hoping someone could explain to me if I should be concerned about this. I am not very knowlagable about this session stuff.

My Configurations:

```
const session = require('express-session');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongo_store = require('connect-mongo');

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err))

app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SEC,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: mongo_store.create({ mongoUrl: process.env.MONGO_URL }),
  cookie: { maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 10 },
}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express session ID's don't change based on session data. If you need to modify sessions use the [store implementations](https://github.com/expressjs/session#session-store-implementation) `.get()` and `.set()` methods.  These will be less fragile as they are what is used by express, they cover all the implementation details of the store and will work the same way if you change the backing store.

```
const { promisify } = require('node:util')
const connect_mongo = require('connect-mongo')

const mongo_store = connect_mongo.create({ mongoUrl: process.env.MONGO_URL })
const mongoStoreGet = promisify(mongo_store.get).bind(mongo_store)
const mongoStoreSet = promisify(mongo_store.set).bind(mongo_store)

app.use(session({
  store: mongo_store,
}));

async someFunction(data){
  const sid = data.metadata.session_id
  const session_data = await mongoStoreGet(sid)
  if (!session_date) throw new Error(`No session [${sid}]`)
  session_data.customer_id = data.customer
  await mongoStoreSet(sid, session_data)
}
```

Also note that modifying the session store while a request is in flight may end up with the users req.session writing back over those changes.